# jQuery clearInterval doesn't work for different functions

Tags: jquery, clearinterval

Does anyone know, why `clearInterval(interval)` doesn't work in my script? I don't get any error in the console log. I have no idea why I can't stop the interval.

Thank you for your support.

```js
var interval;

$(document).on('click', '#register-continue', function() {
  $('.modal-register-form :input[type=text], .modal-register-form :input[type=email], .modal-register-form :input[type=password]').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val().length === 0) {
      interval = setInterval(function() {
        console.log('count')
        $('.modal-register-form :input[type=text], .modal-register-form :input[type=email], .modal-register-form :input[type=password]').each(function() {
          if (($(this).val().length != 0) && (!($(this).is(':focus')))) {
            $(this).css({
              border: '1px solid #e5e5e5'
            });
          }

          if (($(this).val().length === 0) && (!($(this).is(':focus')))) {
            $(this).css({
              border: '1px solid #fe0000'
            });
          }
        });
      }, 10);
    }
  });
});

$(document).on('click', '#register-submit', function() {
  clearInterval(interval);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal-register-form">
  <div class="user-input">
    <input class="first-name" type="text" placeholder="Vorname">
    <input class="last-name" type="text" placeholder="Nachname">
  </div>
  <button type="button" id="register-continue" class="register">continue</button>
  <button type="button" id="register-submit" class="register">submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually your issue is most likely related to that you have a single variable `interval` that you are trying to store multiple intervals in (your logic is in an each).  So your only going to be clearing the last interval.  Your losing your references to previous intervals created.

Comment: Instead of checking the DOM every 10ms for new input use events: [jQuery Learning Center -> Events](https://learn.jquery.com/events/)

Comment: I agree with Andreas.  Stick a `required` class on the elements that require input.  In the script, find all the elements with a class of `.required`, and bind an `change` event handler to them.  If they do not have a value, give them the error border, otherwise remove the error border if it exists.

Comment: That's a great idea, but: it changes the border color while the input field is focused. It should change if the focus is not on it. How is that possible? Any ideas?